# Django urlpattern doesn't work

Tags: python, django, url

I created very simple project, but it shows me Django 404 error page (debug mode is On).

urls.py:

```
....

urlpatterns = patterns('',
    (r'^news/', include('news.urls')),
)
```

news/urls.py:

```
....

urlpatterns = patterns('news.views',
    (r'^$', 'news'),
)
```

I also have "news" in INSTALLED_APPS.

When I open

```
http://localhost/news/
```

in browser Django shows me 404 error:

```
" ... Page not found. Request URL: http://localhost/news// ..."
```

What's wrong with my urls?

Comment: Do you see the URLs from news in the debug output page?

Comment: Do you mean list of available urls? No, this block is empty.

Comment: Do you have `APPEND_SLASH=True` in your settings?

Comment: @limelights `APPEND_SLASH` defaults to True, it's a normal behaviour. One should explicitly set it to False in order to turn it off.

Comment: @AlexParakhnevich Yes, it does, but his urls does not map against `/` it maps against nothing so `APPEND_SLASH` would actually render a 404.

Comment: I didn't have APPEND_SLASH in my settings so I tried to add it. Doesn't work anyway (true and false).

Comment: @limelights true, I also see that. What I mean - that's not the root of the problem, but just a consequence. @Phantom try changing `'news.views'` to `''`

Comment: Try to rename `news` function to `news_list`.

Comment: Replaced 'news.views' with '' and renamed news function in views.py - same 404 page.

Comment: django's default server is 127.0.0.1:8000 -- is this your problem?

Comment: I started fastcgi via manage.py on 8080 port

Comment: @Phantom, try ``http://localhost:8080/news/``

Comment: As said [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/20656087/6555866) you forgot `url(r'^$', 'news.views.news')`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Django urlpattern "didn't match"](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20655812/django-urlpattern-didnt-match)

Answer (score 0):

Your urls.py says "Call a function `def news(request)` inside the file `views.py` in the app `news`. Does this function exist?

Comment: Yes, I have views.py in news folder. There is news function.

Answer (score 0):

You have two slash in the end of url. maybe it's answer

Comment: Yes, I know that. I tried 2, 1 and 0 slashes - no difference.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that news is ur app name and news is the view name also.
Try this in news/urls.py:

```
urlpatterns = patterns('',
    (r'^$', 'news.views.news'),
)
```

Your code should work