# Django urlpattern "didn't match"

Tags: python, django, url

I have the following code in my urls.py:

```
urlpatterns = patterns('',
    (r'^news/', include('news.urls')),
)
```

When I try to open

```
http://localhost/news
```

or

```
http://localhost/news/
```

in the browser django shows me 404 page:

```
Using the URLconf defined in python.urls, Django tried these URL patterns, in this order:

^news/

The current URL, , didn't match any of these.
```

**UPD:**

news/urls.py:

```
from django.conf.urls.defaults import *
from django.views.generic.simple import direct_to_template

urlpatterns = patterns('news.views',
    (r'^$', 'news'),
)
```

There is views.py in news directory and it contains news function.

And news module is added to INSTALLED_APPS.

Why it cannot find news pattern? Any suggestions?

Comment: Show us your `news/urls.py`?

Comment: `URLconf defined in python.urls`  <- python.urls? Really?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Django's URL regex engine is failing](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18390217/djangos-url-regex-engine-is-failing)

Comment: I've never heard of loca. Sounds nice (you're missing an l here --> loca**l**host/news)

Comment: Yes, 'loca...' is typo in my question

Comment: Just making sure you didn't try that for you browser as well

Comment: Try going to `http://localhost/blablabla`. With DEBUG=True you should be able to see a list of available URLs. Do you see news in there?

Comment: Yes, it shows me news as available url

Comment: Did any of the answers solve your problem? If not, please provide more details, error messages etc.

Answer (score 3):

Looks like you forgot the `url()` function:

Try this instead:

```
from django.conf.urls import url

urlpatterns = patterns('',
    url(r'^news/', include('news.urls')),
)
```

and news/urls.py:

```
from django.conf.urls.defaults import *
from django.views.generic.simple import direct_to_template
from django.conf.urls import url

urlpatterns = patterns('news.views',
    url(r'^$', 'news'),
)
```

Answer (score 0):

In which port your application launches? When I see your tries `http://locahost/news` it might be that you forgot to use the right port.

Try to visit `http://localhost:8000/` and `http://localhost:8000/news`.

Comment: I started fastcgi via manage.py runfcgi host=127.0.0.1 port=8080 and I added fastcgi_pass 127.0.0.1:8080; to the nginx virtual host file

Answer (score 0):

I think it may be a problem with your views.py this url on the django docs tells you how to dispatch the urls properley

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/http/urls/